# Need to concatenate to a field value, after checking if value [isnull]

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, isnull, ssms-2012

I have a stored procedure where I'm pulling data from a table. The value in the field can either be NULL or a number value (ex: 15).

I am hoping to display this value with a `$`, however I'm finding it a little hard to do that, since I'm checking if the fieldvalue `isnull`, if it is, I am setting value to `0.0`. This is what it looks like.

```
''Amount Paid''= isnull(tbl_A.AmountPaid,''0.0'')
```

is there an alternative way to do this so that tbl_A.AmountPaid is displayed with $ in front of it if it isn't NULL?

sample data : 93.39
I would like to display it as `$ 93.39` once it's checked that the value is not NULL

Comment: please tag database name and add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: SELECT concat('Amount paid: $ ',+isnull(i,0))    ……..or...….               select i, 'paid: $ ' + cast(isnull(2.3*i,0.0) as varchar(20)) from test where i=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below to add the $ sign before the amount. In this way, $ sign will show for both case if values are there or NULL.

```
SELECT '$ '+CAST(ISNULL(tbl_A.AmountPaid,0.0) AS VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use concatenation:

```
coalesce(concat('$', tbl_A.AmountPaid), '0.0')
```

If you want the `$0.0`, then either:

```
coalesce(concat('$', tbl_A.AmountPaid), '$0.0')
```

or:

```
concat('$', coalesce(tbl_A.AmountPaid, 0))
```

Comment: although i have SQL SERVER 2012 - concat doesn't seem to work, says it's not recognized. i googled and it shows that concat was introduced in 2012

Answer (score 1):

> AmountPaid is displayed with $ in front of it if it isn't NULL

The following query will add `$` in front, if the amount is not null. For the NULL values it will return the AmoutPaid as empty with out `$` sign.

```
SELECT Id, 
       IIF(CONCAT('', AmountPaid) <> '', CONCAT('$ ', AmountPaid), '') AS AmountPaid
FROM Testtable
```

In case if you want `0.0` instead of empty value, use

```
IIF(CONCAT('', AmountPaid) <> '', CONCAT('$ ', AmountPaid), '0.0') AS AmountPaid
```

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @Testtable TABLE (Id int, AmountPaid DECIMAL (9,2));

INSERT INTO @Testtable (Id, AmountPaid) VALUES
(1, 38.89), (2, NULL), (3, 14.2), (4, NULL);

SELECT Id, 
       IIF(CONCAT('', AmountPaid) <> '', CONCAT('$ ', AmountPaid), '') AS AmountPaid
FROM @Testtable
```

Output:

```
Id  AmountPaid
--------------
1   $ 38.89
2   
3   $ 14.20
4
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle with sample data**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e76ebf1d701d1675c8d35147f301b267)